# Selective Harmonization using a document value in Data Hub

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

Is it possible to selectively harmonize documents not just filtered on collections but also based on a specific document's value?

Currently, below is the sample code in my  collector plugin in Data Hub:

```
/*
* Collect IDs plugin
*
* @param options - a map containing options. Options are sent from Java
*
* @return - an array of ids or uris
*/
function collect(options) {
// by default we return the URIs in the same collection as the Entity name
return cts.uris(null, null, cts.andQuery([cts.collectionQuery("LoadCollection"),cts.collectionQuery("SourceCollection"), cts.collectionQuery("Entity1")])); 

module.exports = {collect: collect
};
```

If I want to include in the filter a specific value from a document (filter by ElementID), what code modification should I add to only harmonize specific documents with this element filter?

Below is a sample document for Entity1:

```
<envelope xmlns="http://marklogic.com/entity-services">
  <headers/>
  <triples/>
  <instance>
    <Entity1 xmlns="">
      <ElementID>WM</Element1>
      <Color>Red</Color>
      <Shape>Circle</Shape>
      <Size>Small</Size>
      <Location></Location>
   </Entity1>
  <attachments/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [cts.elementValueQuery](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.elementValueQuery) :

```
cts.uris(null, null, cts.andQuery([cts.elementValueQuery(xs.QName("ElementId"), "WM"), cts.collectionQuery("LoadCollection"), cts.collectionQuery("SourceCollection"), cts.collectionQuery("Entity1")]));
```

Comment: @Rob-The XQuery which i have wrote looks correct ? :) Just wanted to know if that will work correctly.

Comment: To add to the answer provided by Rob: you can use all cts queries inside here, and you are not constrained to just using cts.uris either. As the comment above the code states: `@return - an array of ids or uris`. You could also return unique values based on some range index using something like cts:values instead of cts:uris.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply modify your `collector.xqy`code as below-

```
let $uris := cts:search(doc()/*:envelope/*:instance/*:Entity1,
               cts:and-query((
                 cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("ElementID"),"WM","exact"),      
                 cts:collection-query(("YourCollectionName"))
               )) )
for $i in $uris
    return fn:base-uri($i)
```

Please note I have written this code in `XQuery` but your `collector.xqy` looks in `JavaScript`.

As per my understanding you can use `XQuery` code as well with few modifictaions as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi Shalini! Thanks for the response. Do you have the code version in Javascript? I tried to convert it myself but encounter errors

Comment: I am not much good at JavaScript. But i think you can try and modify it like cts:search--> cts.search and so on. Just few syntax modification will help.

Comment: @Shalini This code is functionally correct but very inefficient. It's much faster to use cts:uris than to load documents into memory, iterate through them and determine the URI. The XPath expression in the first param of cts:search is also unnecessary.

Comment: @RobS. Thank you for your feedback. I will test it the way you said in my local host using cts:uris.